# GORM Transactions (and Locking)

Tags: postgresql, go, transactions, go-gorm, locks

I understand GORM offers support to wrap commands in transactions, for recovery in case of failures. But it's unclear to me (from the docs) if GORM transactions support some form of row locking or table locking. If so, I would love to know how that works

I have gone through the docs and read through a couple of questions on stack overflow but haven't found anything

Answer (score 1):

Gorm allows you to explicitly lock a row. The example below is taken from [the docs](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Locking-FOR-UPDATE):

```
db.Clauses(clause.Locking{
  Strength: "UPDATE",
  Options: "NOWAIT",
}).Find(&users)
```

Comment: do i need to apply this row level lock for executing only one query. or dbms will do automatically for me.